# Back/Forward button between 3 images

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am trying to make a function that can go forward and backwards between 3 images, depending on which button is pressed.
So for now I have made a function for forward and backwards button:

Updated code:

```
var img1 = "images2/page1.jpg";
var img2 = "images2/page2.jpg";
var img3 = "images2/page3.jpg";

function back() {
  var page = document.getElementById("page_1");
  if (page.src == img3) {
    page.src = img2;
  } else if (page.src == img2) {
    page.src = img1;
  } return page.src;
}

function forward() {
  var page = document.getElementById("page_1");

  if (page.src == img1) {
    page.src = img2;
  } else if (page.src == img2) {
    page.src = img3;
  } return page;
}
```

But when I run it in my HTML document, the buttons do nothing.

HTML:

```
<script src="indiv.js"></script>
    <img id="page_1" src="images2/page1.jpg" height="400"><br />
        <button type="button" onclick="back()">Last page</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="forward()">Next page</button>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you from the newbie.

Comment: 1. you are not using `page` in your checks, however you're in luck, because you can directly reference `page_1` (since that's the id) 2. the first order of debugging is to check your variables. `Use console.log(page_1.src);` and you will find that it's the full URL, not the relative one from your HTML, which is the reason why none of your checks works. 3. if your forward code had worked, you'd have jumped from page1 to page3 right away because both checks would've evaluated to true.

Comment: The solution here is to remove all HTML concerns from your program *unless* it's about output. Keep the current image in a variable, change that, then update the src based on that. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3oym6ke5/

Comment: Chris G is on it, but I think R.E should go back and rethink the code, and come up with a solution that makes it dynamic. Just think how you should program this you have 1000 images. If you do that properly, you only need one method and about six rows of code.

Answer (score 2):

Check this code:

```js
var img1 = "https://www.illumina.com/content/dam/illumina-marketing/images/company/featured-articles/bottlenose_dolphin.png"
  var img2 = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/65/d6/cf/65d6cfcb2bb5193d6d160157b34b2bd0.jpg"
  var img3 = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d6/98/88/d698888c81f296032bd595f758b76dc5.jpg"

function back() {
  var page = document.getElementById("page_1");
  
  if (page.src == img3) {
    page.src = img2;
  } else if (page.src == img2) {
    page.src = img1;
  } else if (page.src == img1) {
    page.src = img3;
  }
}

function forward() {
  var page = document.getElementById("page_1");
  
  if (page.src == img1) {
    page.src = img2;
  }else if (page.src == img2) {
    page.src = img3;
  }else if (page.src == img3) {
    page.src = img1;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id = "page_1" src = "https://www.illumina.com/content/dam/illumina-marketing/images/company/featured-articles/bottlenose_dolphin.png" height = "200"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="back()">Last Page</button>
<button type="button" onclick="forward()">Next page</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, makes sense!
But when I try the exact same thing on my code (with my own images of course), still nothing happens.

Do you have any idea what the reason could be?

Comment: @R.E. Can you share code after making changes so i can go through it and can help with it.

Comment: Thank you @BeenaShetty!
I have updated the code now, think it might be something obvious, but I just can't spot it after looking a while.

Comment: @R.E. Issue is with your image src written in Javascript. You need to compare with the full URL of the image as it is returning full url in image src. Try adding console.log(page.src) in javascript. You will come to know what URL  is it getting printed. And then add the image url in javascript.

Comment: I tried the URL, and it worked. But it can only work on my own computer that way, with the URL from local image.. Did you mean something else?

Comment: You would be deploying the code on server and hosting somewhere that time use the image url where the image is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to maintain an array of images you want to cycle through. Then have a index variable to keep track of which image to show currently. Forward and backward buttons just increase or decrease the index variable by one.

```
<div>
    <img id="page_1" src="" height="400">
    <button type="button" onclick="back()">Last page</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="forward()">Next page</button>
</div>
<script>
    //array of images
    let map = ["https://www.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_444x250/HT/p2/2020/05/21/Pictures/_037138a2-9b47-11ea-a010-c71373fc244b.jpg",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
        "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg"
    ]

    //index variable initially set to first image
    let index = 0;
    document.getElementById("page_1").src = map[index];

    //forward button logic
    function forward() {
        index = (index + 1) % 3;
        document.getElementById("page_1").src = map[index];
    }

    //backward button logic
    function back() {
        index = (index - 1 < 0) ? 2 : index - 1;
        document.getElementById("page_1").src = map[index];
    }
</script>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anweshHdWorks/pen/JjKoPJg)